# manipulating 15+ million records in mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, rdbms, database

I got a user table containing 15+ million records and while doing the registration function i wish to check whether the username already exist. I did indexing for username  column and when i run the query "`select count(uid) from users where username='webdev'"` ,. hmmm, its keep on loading blank screen finally hanged up. I'm doing this in my localhost with php 5 & mysql 5. So suggest me some technique to handle this situation.

Is that **mongodb** is good alternative for handling this process in our local machine?

Thanks,
Nithish.

Comment: I don't really understand your error, but do you have an index on "username" ... that would sure help :)

Comment: run this query, then edit the question with the results: `explain select count(uid) from users where username='webdev'`

Comment: For reference, we have a user table with over 40 million rows and we perform nearly the same query every time a registration occurs.  The query should take fractions of a second on a properly indexed, correctly designed table.

Comment: A select is pretty useless, it can't guarantee any uniqueness. You need a unique constraint (a.k.a. unique index).

Comment: So did you guys check this query on your localhost and somewhat ok now but if i compare one more field AGE along with username, Then again hang up :(

Comment: Is mongodb is the solution to avoid this type of situation in future?

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to check that it exists or not, try not using the `count`. Just a simple `select username from users where username='webdev' LIMIT 1` may be faster.

ALSO, change the column type to `varchar`, if it's not already so. Don't user `text` type. It's much much slower.

Comment: not really, `count(*) or count(username)` does not slow things up

Comment: @ajreal, but `LIMIT 1` can speed things up :)

Comment: @ajreal, yes BUT the OP wrote, "i wish to check whether the username already exist". For that matter, checking it with `LIMIT 1` is fine. Isn't it? If I am missing something here, please correct me.

Comment: @shamittomar - **1.** count is not slow, but count(uid) might slow **2.** with limit does not work better than just `count(*)` **3.** with proper define index, count=constant

Comment: @shamittomar: hmm. i belive using char is better than using varchar in this case if the HDD is not a problem. also i run a site similar and the username usually never goes above 40 charaters and hardly goes above 25-30 charaters. so what i suggest to do is put a charater limit of 40 charater or something for the username feild ( or find the highest existing now) and change the column type to char(<thatno>) .. why this because if using varchar the pointer needs to calculate the length of each username before checking it.

Comment: So did you guys check this query on your localhost and somewhat ok now but if i compare one more field AGE along with username including limit 1, Then again hang up :(

Comment: Is mongodb is the solution to avoid this type of situation in future?

Answer (score 2):

This might be a moot point, but to test and see if the user name already exists, I would issue the following query (a slight modification on shamittomar's query):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'webdev';
```

This will, by default, return the only instance of "webdev" in the "username" column; if you add more parameters, though, it could change your results. An example being, if you run

```
SELECT DISTINCT `user_id`, `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'webdev';
```

it would return all unique combinations of "user_id" and "username".

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is change the indexing of the username from `index to unique` that will make the search much much faster and like shamittomar said add a `limit 1` at the end even though it will only help if the value already exists.

Comment: A unique index is what the OP needs, a SELECT can never guarantee any uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

your user name is unique so you must set limit of 1 in your query it will be more faster

```
select count(uid) from users where username='webdev' limit 1
```